# Mini cooper 2003

Tags: cooling-system, mini-cooper

Hi I have an issue with my 2003 mini.
Temp is only running at quarter and after a while if I am stationary it will go up to  half way and no further, but when it his halfway it will make a farting type sound and eml comes on, then after a while goes. Also sounds like exhaust is not a consistent noise.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you explain a little better what's going on? Why is it an issue it only goes 1/2 way? Most vehicles that's where it's normal. Can you better explain "farting"? What does EML mean? What do you mean by exhaust is not consistent? Have you done any work to it? What has changed?

Comment: So, temp runs at the quarter marker. No issues other than car does not idle right when stationary, and after being stationary for a period of time the temperature rises to the half way mark. I.e. Normal running temp. But when it hits the halfway marker on the temperature gauge for a few minutes it then makes a weird bubbling sound. Then the engine management light comes on for a day and then clears. The problem only occurs when stationary.

Comment: Have you checked for codes?

Comment: Not yet, shall hopefully do this within the week. Any suggestions as to what it could be?

Comment: Getting the codes read would be a great step towards knowing what's going on. Right now there's just way too many things it could be.